# Cannot scroll vertically in Design View in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot scroll vertically in Design View in Android Studio 2.0, so i cannot see any widgets in the bottom part of the design view.Does anybody know how to fix or is it the bug?

Comment: Please attach screen shot

Comment: Upgrade your Studio to 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You will only be able to scroll ( also in design view) if you are using ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

The Design view in android studio show in perspective to virtual device screen size you have selected, it dont scroll in design view instead you have to test it on the live device instead. Again here you can try to change the virtual mobile view size from top menu to nexus 6 or other with high resolution and it might show you the full view of your design.

Comment: Now i 'm designing for 8.0 '' tablet, so approximately similar is Nexus 7, so i choose Nexus 7 from Top Menu, it cannot show the whole layout, but if i choose like that Nexus 10, i can see the whole layout in Design View.

Comment: As I told the design view will try to give you the best estimated UI view and it will never look exactly same in real device so I would advice to test it on device.